# How do you install Visual Studio 2010 Professional?

Tags: software-installation

How can I install Visual Studio 2010 framework4 on Ubuntu 13.04?

My project was written with Visual Studio (visual basic) 2010 in Windows 7. Now that I installed Ubuntu 13.04, can I complete my project with it?

Answer (score 0):

By adding the WINE repo and installing wine1.7 you should be able to run Visual Studio 2010 on Ubuntu...  To add repo and install type these lines into terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install wine1.7
```

...now you can right click any windows .exe file and select "Open with Wine Windows Program Loader" which you can set to be the default action...